# Ajax loaded buttons bound with delegated event handlers fire multiple times on laravel pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, laravel-5

Okay, so I'm having some interesting problems.  I have a web app where the homepage is comprised of a few tabbed div elements.  Within each tabbed div different pages are loaded via AJAX to allow for smooth user interface and workflow.  I am having an issue with my Laravel pagination.  The functions I have designed to prevent the default redirect are working as I intended but each time the AJAX-loaded pages are rendered it seems to add additional onclick events.  Below is a screenshot of what I mean.
[image: Mutliple Click Events Fire per Click]

As you can see in the network panel, each click of the pagination links triggers multiple fires.  While they all return successful pages after a few clicks this seriously degrades performance.  I would appreciate any insight into why this might be happening.

Below is the Javascript I use to both assign the event handlers and the functions they call.  You will note I already use the .off->.on methodology.

```js
function myPages(origin,div_tag) //origin is an identifier of where the pagination links live
//div_tag indicates where the resultant page will be output to.
{
  mydata={tag: div_tag};
  $(origin).off('click','.pagination a',mydata, directPages);
  $(origin).on('click','.pagination a',mydata, directPages);
}
//event handles are passed the event always, any additional data included is passed
// as a property (i.e. event.data).
function directPages(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var url=$(this).attr('href');
  var tag = e.data.tag;
  loadComponent(url,tag);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script>
  //The first argument defines the parent element used in 
  //delegating the event handler to the child elements.  The
  //second identifies the element into which the resulting 
  //html code that is return will be rendered.
  myPages("div.mysources","#sources");
</script>
```

I am trying to get a firm enough understanding of the model in which these events are occurring to avoid them but I'm fine with some defensive coding approaches as well.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm an overworked idiot.  The above code works beautifully to restrict the click events.  I had recently made modifications to the myPages function to make it more specific, using the element just outside the pagination links to specify exactly which ones to link with each function and in which div to render the result.  I had simply not run the `gulp` command since I had made those changes so it was not pushed up.  Hopefully someone else will find this useful though.